# QNetworkAccessManager POST, and after that GET doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I want with POST method connect to a webpage for e.g. so i go to login page "www.example.com/login" and after i succsesfully login I want to go for e.g. here "www.example.com/index.php" but i cant get this to work becouse it still returns me "www.example.com/login" no matter what i try.

Here is my code.

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager;



 manager = new QNetworkAccessManager ();
     QNetworkRequest req;

address =("www.example/index.php");

        manager->setCookieJar(new QNetworkCookieJar);

        req.setHeader(req.UserAgentHeader,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2");
        req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.setUrl(QUrl("www.example.com/login"));


            QByteArray postData;
            postData.append("login_user=user&");
            postData.append("login_passwd=Pass");

    connect (manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(writeToTxt(QNetworkReply  *)));



    manager->post(req, postData);
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(address));

    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("www.example.com/example.html")));
```

and here is my slot

```
void HtmlSource::writeToTxt(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    qDebug() << "atsakymas" << endl;
    if(reply->isOpen()){

        //qDebug() << reply->readAll();

            QFile file( "1.txt" );

        if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) )
        {

            file.write(reply->readAll());
            file.close();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is this a whitespace polyglot?

Comment: You could connect to the signal "authenticationRequired" of the QNetworkAccessManager to handle your login and try to access the secured page directly. Look in the documentation for the class "QAuthenticator"

Comment: Well, I connect successfully and get source code of login page without any errors. I believe  session should be still alive after I do post, but I don't know how to correctly go to another page. Maybe after login I should ask for cookies and use them when I ask for another page.

Comment: What do you mean by whitespace polyglot? Well my gui is in qml and back end is in c++